# SQL group_concat why am i getting values in wrong order?

Tags: php, sql, json

Why am i getting my values in the wrong order when using group_concat and parsing them in json?

Here is my code

```
$sql = "select
          e_name,
          a_shortcut,
          GROUP_CONCAT(case
            when t_rank = 1 then  a_shortcut
            when t_rank = 2 then  a_shortcut
            when t_rank = 3 then  a_shortcut
          end separator ',') as group_con 
        from
          team inner join event on team.EID = event.eid Where e_type = 'nonsport'  group by event.eid";                         

         $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


         $response = array();

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $ar=explode(',',$row['group_con']);
        array_push($response, array("e_name"=>$row[0],"First"=>$ar[0], 
        "Second"=>$ar[1], "Third"=>$ar[2]));

        } 
echo json_encode (array("nresults"=>$response));
```

Here is the output that is giving me

```
    {"nresults":[

{"e_name":"AAA","First":"3rd","Second":"2nd","Third":"1st"},
{"e_name":"BBB","First":"2nd","Second":"1st","Third":"3rd"}
```

Here is my expected output

```
    {"nresults":[

{"e_name":"AAA","First":"1st","Second":"2nd","Third":"3rd"},

{"e_name":"BBB","First":"1st","Second":"2nd","Third":"3rd"}
```

Comment: You should format your results so the ordering that you want is clear.

Comment: in the database sir?

Comment: Use `order by` when selecting from the table where you are getting the a_shortcut before you do the `inner join`.

Comment: @ultrajohn can you make it an answer sir. So i can accept it

Comment: @orange, sure. there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by` when selecting from the table where you are getting the a_shortcut before you do the `inner join`.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\atfest\cpanel\mobile\NonSportsResult.php on line 22
{"nresults":[]}

Comment: select
          e_name,
          a_shortcut,
          GROUP_CONCAT(case
            when t_rank = 1 then  a_shortcut
            when t_rank = 2 then  a_shortcut
            when t_rank = 3 then  a_shortcut
          end separator ',') as group_con 
        from
  order by t_rank
          team inner join event on team.EID = event.eid Where e_type = 'nonsport'  group by event.eid

Comment: posted my sql query sir

Comment: I know can you post the correct one sir, cant seem to find the error